# Duplicate entry '' for key 'users_email_unique' empty field

Tags: mysql, laravel-4

I have two types of users - real and fake.
Fake users are employees, that don't use the system.
Real users use their email address to login. So my users migration has `$table->string('email')->unique();`.

The problem is that fake users may not have an email address. I can add first fake user no problem, but the second one generates error `SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '' for key 'users_email_unique'`.

What should I do?

Comment: Insert fake users as NULL,this work because mysql treats NULL values as unqiue

Comment: why dont u make two tables like `tblrealUsers` and `tblfakeUsers`?

Comment: The email field cannot be unique if you are going to have more than one user with the "" email. Yo have to delete the restriction or use any "tricky" solution for example: "fakeXX@fake.com" being XX the user ID.

Comment: @Mihai really? but how it works?

Comment: If you use an orm you should want to be database agnostic and using null is not a good idea for many reason, first is that only mysql is that dumb. Take the answer from Enrique that ninjed me xD

Comment: @LucaBruzzone So how using empty string for a few employees is smart but NULLs is dumb?

Comment: I never suggested to use an empty string and I said that mysql id dumb to treat null as unique (because you can make a mess in the indexes) In my answer I was suggesting to remove the rows or use a fake email (which are unique and can be sharded eventually and if someone wants to change the db can do it without pain)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like `users_email_unique` is your primary key. This means that when you insert your first fake user with a blank email address, the blank entry is counted as a unique entry. When your second blank entry is entered it violates entity integrity (duplicate primary keys).

```
users_email_unique    unique?
_________________     _______
email@email.com       yes
blank                 yes
blank                 no
```

If you want multiple blank entries you could allow `users_email_unique` to be `null`, however, a primary key column [cannot contain `null` values](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_primarykey.asp):

```
users_email_unique   unique?
__________________   ________
email@email.com      yes
NULL                 yes
NULL                 yes
```

If you are using `users_email_unique` as your primary key then, as pointed out in the comments, you may need to either:

- generate a random unique email temporarily for 'fake' users
- reconsider your primary key for your table (perhaps some form of unique ID?)
- perhaps split into two tables, one for 'real' users and one for 'fake'

Comment: I went for `$table->dropUnique('email_users_unique');`, but I'd rather have set email to `NULL` if user is fake and his email is not provided.

Comment: @EdmundSulzanok If I try that I get this error: ` SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1091 Can't DROP 'email_u  
  sers_unique'; check that column/key exists (SQL: alter table `users` drop i  
  ndex `email_users_unique`)`

Comment: @Hillcow could it mean, that your email column is already not unique?

Answer (score 0):

You can act in 2 ways:

- delete the line where the email is null (if there are user that aren't fake this process will kill their accounts)
- give a random email with a custom domain like random@myfakedomain.fake and then you can control in the class when you log in if the mail matches the fake mail and ask to the user to insert a real mail if he want to continue using the website

(eventually you can have the 2nd solution for a while and then pass to the 1st)

Answer (score 0):

[image]

For any other person who might be  looking for a solution in 2020

Look for the this **indexes** on the **users table** in phpmyadmin.

Deleting the **user_up_number_unique** index might solve the problem