# How to make empty string as null value to allow duplicate empty strings in optional field?

Tags: sql, postgresql, unique-constraint, unique-key

I have an email field that's optional. The regex works fine accepting the empty string (^$) but now the issue is that the empty string is considered a unique entry. It will only allow one user to register without entering an email address. I know I have to set it to null, but not sure how.

Something like this:

[Duplicate entry '' for key 'users_email_unique' empty field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31984272/duplicate-entry-for-key-users-email-unique-empty-field)

[Error: Duplicate entry '' for key 'email'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33673946/error-duplicate-entry-for-key-email)

Comment: Are you saying that setting the field to `null` would work? If so, why aren't you doing that then?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a trigger that converts blanks to nulls on insert or update:

```
create trigger null_email
before insert or update on users
for each row
new.email = nullif(old.email, '')
```

Or convert blanks to nulls on insert:

```
insert into users (..., email, ...)
values (..., nullif(?, ''), ...)
```

The trigger is the better way, because it handles data from any source, whereas method 2 would require the insert/update SQL of every application to conform to the "no blanks" rule.

Comment: I'd agree with you on this, papering over the problem with a partial index seems like a gift that keeps on giving (grief and confusion).

Answer (score 9):

You could use [partial index](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.0/static/indexes-partial.html):

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX idx_unq_tab_email ON tab(email) WHERE TRIM(email) <> '';
```

**[DBFiddle Demo](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=93903ca94dec5872c8a6eef41c847dd0)**

That way you still have `UNIQUE` constraint plus original value.

Comment: The downside of this is that all `email is null` queries would have to become `email is null or trim(email) = ''`. I think you'd be better off in the long run if you cleaned up the data before putting it in the table.